# Galleon Wallet Issue: sent transaction locked in pending

Tags: transactions, error, galleon

Attempting to send XTZ from Galleon Wallet from either TZ or K1 addresses both transactions are locked in pending. tzscan generates the following 404 error:

"path [{kind:generic,error:Prevalidator is not running, cannot inject the operation.}] not found"

Using the latest wallet 8.2b.  Derivation path: 44'/1729/0'/0'/0'

Anyone have thoughts what to do here? It was working fine a couple of days ago.

Comment: There was indeed an issue with Cryptonomic Tezos nodes but it has now been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having issues with sending transactions with Galleon Wallet Heres a fix suggested both in riot and telegram. Galleon has been having issues with it's nodes apparently.

Go to Settings -> Choose a Different Node -> Set Up Your Custom Tezos Node

Switch the tezos node to https://mainnet-node.tzscan.io:443

I named the custom node: tzscan and left API Key blank.

That seemed to work fine.